# How to display other columns in Mac Finder?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, finder, properties

How can I get Finder to display other file properties so I can sort on those instead

e.g. bit rate

You can do this in windows XP and I'm finding it incredibly frustrating that such an option does not appear to be available in OS X

Comment: You can search (or "filter") for specific bit rates using Spotlight. It's not as easy but if you just want to trash/replace/re-rip low bitrate items, search for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Finder doesn't deal with MP3 tags I can think of two options:

1. Use iTunes to manage your music, sort by bitrate there.
2. Create a script that adds bitrate information for MP3 files to the comments field. The Finder can show and sort by comment. You'd have to use a combination of something like  the [mp3info](http://ruby-mp3info.rubyforge.org/) library for Ruby and Applescript. A bit more involved than I have time for tonight. :)

Comment: Write a script..lol      I guess that this isn't supported as according to steve jobs' way of thinking, you will have obtained all your music via itunes, so why would you have duplicates etc

Answer (score 1):

If you're in list view (View menu > as List), open the view options (View > Show View Options) and it'll show a list of columns you can display.  However, bit rate is not one of the available properties; it's not going to have anything format-specific (I presume you're interested in the bit rate of MP3 files, or something like that), just general file properties.